# Generic ArrayList in C

Tags: c

I have made a Java like ArrayList class in C for educational purposes however currently it is only good for integers. I want to make it Generic so it can take any type of data. How do I go about it. I read somewhere about creating a typedef void pointer. Any thoughts ? 
........................................................................................................
    Here is My code

```
#ifndef ARRAYLIST_H
#define ARRAYLIST_H

typedef struct ArrayList ArrayList;
typedef int bool;
#define false 0
#define true 1
struct ArrayList {
    int *con;
    int numElements;
    int conSize;
};

ArrayList *createArrayList();
void freeArrayList(ArrayList *);
void add(ArrayList *, int);
void printList(ArrayList *);
void resize(ArrayList *);
int remove(ArrayList *, int);
bool isEmpty(ArrayList*);
int getNumElements(ArrayList*);
int getConSize(ArrayList*);
#endif

_____________________________________

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"Consts.h"
#include "ArrayList.h"
#define CAPACITY 5
ArrayList *createArrayList() {
    ArrayList *arrayList = malloc(sizeof(ArrayList));
    arrayList->conSize = CAPACITY;
    arrayList->numElements = 0;
    arrayList->con = malloc(sizeof(int) * CAPACITY);
    return arrayList;
}

void freeArrayList(ArrayList * arrayList) {
    if (arrayList == NULL) {
        return;
    }else {
        free(arrayList->con);
        free(arrayList);
    }
}
void add(ArrayList *arrayList, int input) {
    //printf("Num elements in add method before adding %d \n", arrayList->numElements);
    if (arrayList->numElements >= arrayList->conSize) {
        resize(arrayList);
        printf("resized\n");
    }
    int size = arrayList->numElements;
    //add element to the last
    arrayList->con[size] = input;
    arrayList->numElements = arrayList->numElements + 1
}

void resize(ArrayList *arrayList) {
    int num = arrayList->numElements;
    int oldSize = arrayList->conSize;
    int newSize = oldSize + 50;
    int *temp = realloc(arrayList->con, sizeof(type) * newSize);
    if (temp != NULL) {
        arrayList->con = temp;
        arrayList->conSize = newSize;
    }
}

int remove(ArrayList * arrayList, int val) {
    int i = 0;
    while (arrayList->con[i] != val) {
        i++;
    }
    //remove this index
    if (i == arrayList->conSize) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        int removedVal = arrayList->con[i]; int j;
        for (j = i; j < arrayList->numElements ; j++) {
            arrayList->con[j] = arrayList->con[j + 1];
        }
        arrayList->con[j + 1] = NULL;
        arrayList->numElements = arrayList->numElements - 1;
        return removedVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: C doesn't really do "generic" programming. You can use `void*` and a whole bunch of duct-tape, though.

Comment: Sure! Why not? You could change `con` to be a `void *` type. If that's the case, you'll also have to store the size of the type you're storing.

Also you'll run into some problems trying to access con with square bracket notation (like this `arrayList->con[size]`). You'll learn some about pointer arithmetic in C.

Comment: @GandhiGandhi thank you for the reply. I have a little follow up. For eg I am using void* con and in my add method what shall the data type of input be. Because it says you cannot have a void type parameter. Thank you once again

Comment: Right, you can't pass a `void` type parameter to a function because the compiler needs to know what the size of each argument is at compile time. 

What you can do though, is pass a `void *` parameter pointing to the new item to add, and a `size_t` parameter pointing to the size of the size of the new item.

`void add_generic(ArrayList *arrayList, void* input_ptr, size_t input_size);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C generic array implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37496282/c-generic-array-implementation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the array list be able to store any type of data, you need to
1) make `con` a `void` pointer. `void *con;`
2) store additional metadata in the struct about the memory alignment of the type
3) add one more parameter to the constructor of array list, which is the additional metadata mentioned in 2)
4) when allocating memory, use the stored metadata instead of `sizeof(whatever)`, like `temp=malloc(stored_metadata_about_type*50);`

Also notice that it is not usually a good idea to hardcode `50`, and better declare it as a constant like `buffer_size`.